# InvalidOperationException when trying to add a table to my solution

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor

Here's the exact error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The type 'UserRole' is mapped as a complex type. The Set method, DbSet objects, and DbEntityEntry objects can only be used with entity types, not complex types.
```

There are two columns in the table, it's not complex at all:

```
[UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
[RoleId] [int] NOT NULL
```

Here's the model class:

```
public class UserRole : EntityBase
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the mapping class:

```
public class UserRoleMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserRole>
{
    public UserRoleMap() {
        Property(t => t.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");
        Property(t => t.RoleId).HasColumnName("RoleId");
    }
}
```

It's added to my context as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserRoleMap());
```

And finally here is the code that is throwing the error:

```
var userRoles2 = unitOfWork.Repository<UserRole>().FindById(id);
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Do you add class with dbset https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/dbset.aspx?

Comment: No. But none of the other tables have a DBSet and they all work

Comment: If you update database and other tables  create,please add your dbcontext in your post

Comment: Please provide a [mre].